# simple_html_dom(php parser) not working on a particular website when I connect it to a server

Tags: php, http, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I build a PHP scrapper that scraps a website with the URL (https://www.forebet.com/en/values);
My code for finding the title is:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html=file_get_html("https://www.forebet.com/en/values");
echo $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
```

It DOES work when I am running it on my computer, but it doesn't run on a server. It shows the error message"This page isn’t workingwager1x2.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500".

By enabling the 'PHP error code display function' which is `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` it shows a fatal error before a warning:

1. Warning:
   "file_get_contents(https://www.forebet.com/en/values): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/winbvgmt/wager1x2.com/forbet_scrapper/simple_html_dom.php on line 84"
   Line 79-84 of simple_html_dom is:

   `$contents = file_get_contents( $url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset, $maxLen);`
2. Fatal Error:
   "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on bool in /home/winbvgmt/wager1x2.com/forbet_scrapper/php.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/winbvgmt/wager1x2.com/forbet_scrapper/php.php on line 16". Line 16 is:`echo $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;`

I tried checking it on google.com and it works perfectly for google.

Comment: Presumably the remote server either noticed you're trying to scrape it repeatedly and blocked you based on your IP perhaps, or it looks at things like having a valid user-agent string in your request and rejects if certain things aren't present. Either way, probably that's to try and weed out non-browsers who might be trying to scrape the data!

Comment: P.S. Has it occured to you that maybe such a company doesn't want you to potentially interrupt its revenue stream by displaying data that _they_ created, on _your_ website, effectively taking users away from _their_ site? If they want / allow to to legitimately access their data for any purpose, then more than likely they'll provide an API for you to do so. If they don't, then you can assume you're not supposed to nick their data. You might even get yourself into hot water regarding copyright, or hacking, or things like that, depending on the jurisdiction(s) you're operating in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it for security reason. There are two reason types. One is them is remote server security . Another is local server(hosting) security is blocking when you send request to remote server. Instead of this you may use curl library. For example:

```php
  // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: So Tural Rzaxanov, how can I echo the title of any page with cURL

Comment: Before you should crawl site content with curl which i has showed above. Here $output give to you all data.  After it you can write $html = str_get_html($output); $title = $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;